# Extra "Are you sure?" before destroying a record

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, destroy

On some of my forms, I have an extra popup confirmation "Are you sure?" before it will actually destroy the record. I'm using Rails 4 and simple_form. Here is an example.

I have a model called Promotions and another called PromotionPurchase.

**The models:**

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotion_purchases, dependent: :destroy
end

class PromotionPurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :promotion
end
```

**The schema**

```
create_table "promotion_purchases", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "promotion_id"
  t.string   "status"
  t.string   "stripe_card_token"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.string   "full_name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "promotion_purchases", ["promotion_id"], name: "index_promotion_purchases_on_promotion_id"
add_index "promotion_purchases", ["user_id"], name: "index_promotion_purchases_on_user_id"

create_table "promotions", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "cost_in_cents"
  t.integer  "amount_available"
  t.string   "category"
  t.datetime "start_date"
  t.datetime "end_date"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**And the form:**

```
<div class="content-box">
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @promotion] do |f| %>
  <fieldset id="promotion-form-info">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :category %>
    <%= f.input :cost_in_cents, as: :string %>
    <%= f.input :amount_available, as: :string %>
    <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :date_picker %>
    <%= f.input :end_date, :as => :datetime_picker %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
<% if @promotion.id != nil %>
  <fieldset id="promotion-form-purchases">
    <h3>Purchases:</h3>
    <% if !@purchases.empty? %>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= purchase.full_name %></td>
            <td><%= purchase.user.email if purchase.user %></td>
            <td><%= purchase.phone %></td>
            <td><%= purchase.status %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_admin_promotion_promotion_purchase_path(@promotion, purchase), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
              <%= link_to 'Delete', [:admin, @promotion, purchase], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %> 
              <%= "<- Editing this purchase" if @purchase && purchase.id == @purchase.id %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Add Purchase", new_admin_promotion_promotion_purchase_path(@promotion), class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**And the controller**

```
class Admin::PromotionPurchasesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  before_action :set_promotion
  before_action :set_purchase, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def destroy
    @purchase.destroy
    redirect_to new_admin_promotion_promotion_purchase_path(@promotion), success: 'PromotionPurchase was deleted.'
  end

  private

    def set_promotion
      @promotion = Promotion.find(params[:promotion_id])
    end

    def set_purchase
      @purchase = PromotionPurchase.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Any ideas why I'm seeing "Are you sure?" twice instead of only once when I destroy a PromotionPurchase from the form to edit a Promotion?

In this case, I saw it three times:

[image: A list of purchases connected to this Promotion]
[image: The first "Are you sure?]
[image: The second]
[image: The third]

Comment: Can you post that snapshot?

Comment: can you post you layout, routes file?

Comment: Deleting is destructive.  Claim this is desired behavior to prevent accidental data loss and ship it ;]  /jokes

Answer (score 4):

The code that you posted seems to be ok.

I think that the problems is coming from javascript. (check the console you might see something in there)

Also you maybe imported `jquery_ujs` to many times, try and remove the `jquery_ujs` from `application.js` and see if anything happens, if is imported only once, you should not get that dialog box.

Comment: When I remove that line from the application.js, I do not get the dialog at all and it gives me a routing error.

Comment: Do you see that routing error in the server logs or in the browser?

Comment: That's normal, [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) is responsible for handling the `method` params. Without it, the link becomes a simple *GET* and I guess you don't have a **show** route?

Answer (score 0):

Try just putting a simple `<script>` in the form, and put an alert there. If that alerts 3 times then your problem is loading the file too many times.